# Struts 2 File Upload Interceptor configuration problems

Tags: file-upload, configuration, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I'm having two problems when trying to configure the Struts 2 File Upload Interceptor in my application. I want to change the parameter `maximumSize` (the default value is 2 MB, I need it to be 5 MB) and the message resource `struts.messages.error.file.too.large` (the app locale is pt_BR, so the message is in portuguese, not english).

The app current configuration follows:

**struts.properties**

```
struts.locale=pt_BR 
struts.custom.i18n.resources=MessageResources
```

**struts.xml**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="login" class="br.com.probank.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultLoginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="login" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack" />
    ...
</package>

...
<package name="proposta" namespace="/proposta" extends="default">
    <action name="salvarAnexoProposta" method="salvarAnexoProposta" class="br.com.probank.action.AnexoPropostaAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack">
            <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">5242880</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">/jsp/listagemAnexosPropostaForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/jsp/crudAnexoPropostaForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectLink}</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**MessageResources.properties**

```
...
struts.messages.error.file.too.large=O tamanho do arquivo...
```

There is nothing special about my Action implementation and my JSP code. They follow the example found http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html. When I try to upload a file with more than 5 MB the app shows the message "the request was rejected because its size (6229458) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)" - the default File Upload message with the default maximumSize value.

I try to put the message resource `struts.messages.error.file.too.large` in a struts-messages.properties but the message didn't change after that. What is the proper way to configure the File Upload Interceptor? I'm using Struts 2 2.1.7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found a way to change the upload size limit. :) I changed the `struts.multipart.maxSize` property in `struts.properties` file to the desired value. But the problem with the localized error message still remains...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally solved the entire puzzle! `struts.xml` and `MessageResource.properties` were correctly configured. The problem was **`struts.multipart.maxSize` value**. This value have to be bigger than the desired upload limit (5242880 in my app), so I set it as 10000000. If `struts.multipart.maxSize` value is equal or less then `fileUpload.maximumSize` the library used by Struts 2 to do the upload stops the upload process (and writes the error message) before the file upload interceptor has a chance to do its job.

Answer (score 6):

The solution provided by you isn't entirely correct in the sense that If I want strict upload limits along with i18n, this won't work. I've also created an issue with strut2 for this. Please look at the following link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3177. It's due to be fixed in struts2.1.9 and is already assigned to a struts team member.

In between, I'm using a hack. I browsed the struts2 source code and found the code for FileUploadInterceptor. Using that code, I created my own. Here's the code below. You can find details of problem at the link above. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ValidationAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.Logger;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory;


public class CustomFileUploaderInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4764627478894962478L;

    protected static final Logger LOG =           LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFileUploaderInterceptor.class);
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "no.message.found";

    protected boolean useActionMessageBundle;

    protected Long maximumSize;
    protected Set<String> allowedTypesSet = Collections.emptySet();
    protected Set<String> allowedExtensionsSet = Collections.emptySet();

    public void setUseActionMessageBundle(String value) {
        this.useActionMessageBundle = Boolean.valueOf(value);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the allowed extensions
     *
     * @param allowedExtensions A comma-delimited list of extensions
     */
    public void setAllowedExtensions(String allowedExtensions) {
        allowedExtensionsSet = TextParseUtil.commaDelimitedStringToSet(allowedExtensions);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the allowed mimetypes
     *
     * @param allowedTypes A comma-delimited list of types
     */
    public void setAllowedTypes(String allowedTypes) {
        allowedTypesSet = TextParseUtil.commaDelimitedStringToSet(allowedTypes);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the maximum size of an uploaded file
     *
     * @param maximumSize The maximum size in bytes
     */
    public void setMaximumSize(Long maximumSize) {
        this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor#intercept(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation)
     */
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        ActionContext ac = invocation.getInvocationContext();
        Map<String, Object> params1 = ac.getParameters();
        Set<String> keySet = params1.keySet();
        for(String s : keySet){
            LOG.debug("Key: "+ s +", Value: " + params1.get(s).toString());
        }
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ac.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

        if (!(request instanceof MultiPartRequestWrapper)) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                ActionProxy proxy = invocation.getProxy();
                LOG.debug(getTextMessage("struts.messages.bypass.request", new Object[]{proxy.getNamespace(), proxy.getActionName()}, ac.getLocale()));
            }

            return invocation.invoke();
        }

        ValidationAware validation = null;

        Object action = invocation.getAction();

        if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
            validation = (ValidationAware) action;
        }

        MultiPartRequestWrapper multiWrapper = (MultiPartRequestWrapper) request;

        if (multiWrapper.hasErrors()) {
            String inputName = null;
            if(multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames().hasMoreElements()){
                inputName = (String)multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames().nextElement();

            }
            for (String error : multiWrapper.getErrors()) {
                if (validation != null) {
                    Object[] args = new Object[]{inputName};
                    validation.addActionError(getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.file.too.large", args, ac.getLocale()));
                }
                LOG.error(error);
            }
        }

        // bind allowed Files
        Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames();
        while (fileParameterNames != null && fileParameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            // get the value of this input tag
            String inputName = (String) fileParameterNames.nextElement();

            // get the content type
            String[] contentType = multiWrapper.getContentTypes(inputName);

            if (isNonEmpty(contentType)) {
                // get the name of the file from the input tag
                String[] fileName = multiWrapper.getFileNames(inputName);

                if (isNonEmpty(fileName)) {
                    // get a File object for the uploaded File
                    File[] files = multiWrapper.getFiles(inputName);
                    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                        List<File> acceptedFiles = new ArrayList<File>(files.length);
                        List<String> acceptedContentTypes = new ArrayList<String>(files.length);
                        List<String> acceptedFileNames = new ArrayList<String>(files.length);
                        String contentTypeName = inputName + "ContentType";
                        String fileNameName = inputName + "FileName";

                        for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                            if (acceptFile(action, files[index], fileName[index], contentType[index], inputName, validation, ac.getLocale())) {
                                acceptedFiles.add(files[index]);
                                acceptedContentTypes.add(contentType[index]);
                                acceptedFileNames.add(fileName[index]);
                            }
                        }

                        if (!acceptedFiles.isEmpty()) {
                            Map<String, Object> params = ac.getParameters();

                            params.put(inputName, acceptedFiles.toArray(new File[acceptedFiles.size()]));
                            params.put(contentTypeName, acceptedContentTypes.toArray(new String[acceptedContentTypes.size()]));
                            params.put(fileNameName, acceptedFileNames.toArray(new String[acceptedFileNames.size()]));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    LOG.error(getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.invalid.file", new Object[]{inputName}, ac.getLocale()));
                }
            } else {
                LOG.error(getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.invalid.content.type", new Object[]{inputName}, ac.getLocale()));
            }
        }

        // invoke action
        String result = invocation.invoke();

        // cleanup
        fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames();
        while (fileParameterNames != null && fileParameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String inputValue = (String) fileParameterNames.nextElement();
            File[] files = multiWrapper.getFiles(inputValue);

            for (File currentFile : files) {
                if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    LOG.info(getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.removing.file", new Object[]{inputValue, currentFile}, ac.getLocale()));
                }

                if ((currentFile != null) && currentFile.isFile()) {
                    currentFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Override for added functionality. Checks if the proposed file is acceptable based on contentType and size.
     *
     * @param action      - uploading action for message retrieval.
     * @param file        - proposed upload file.
     * @param contentType - contentType of the file.
     * @param inputName   - inputName of the file.
     * @param validation  - Non-null ValidationAware if the action implements ValidationAware, allowing for better
     *                    logging.
     * @param locale
     * @return true if the proposed file is acceptable by contentType and size.
     */
    protected boolean acceptFile(Object action, File file, String filename, String contentType, String inputName, ValidationAware validation, Locale locale) {
        boolean fileIsAcceptable = false;

        // If it's null the upload failed
        if (file == null) {
            String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.uploading", new Object[]{inputName}, locale);
            if (validation != null) {
                validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
            }

            LOG.error(errMsg);
        } else if (maximumSize != null && maximumSize < file.length()) {
            String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.file.too.large", new Object[]{inputName, filename, file.getName(), "" + file.length()}, locale);
            if (validation != null) {
                validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
            }

            LOG.error(errMsg);
        } else if ((!allowedTypesSet.isEmpty()) && (!containsItem(allowedTypesSet, contentType))) {
            String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed", new Object[]{inputName, filename, file.getName(), contentType}, locale);
            if (validation != null) {
                validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
            }

            LOG.error(errMsg);
        } else if ((! allowedExtensionsSet.isEmpty()) && (!hasAllowedExtension(allowedExtensionsSet, filename))) {
            String errMsg = getTextMessage(action, "struts.messages.error.file.extension.not.allowed", new Object[]{inputName, filename, file.getName(), contentType}, locale);
            if (validation != null) {
                validation.addFieldError(inputName, errMsg);
            }

            LOG.error(errMsg);
        } else {
            fileIsAcceptable = true;
        }

        return fileIsAcceptable;
    }

    /**
     * @param extensionCollection - Collection of extensions (all lowercase).
     * @param filename            - filename to check.
     * @return true if the filename has an allowed extension, false otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean hasAllowedExtension(Collection<String> extensionCollection, String filename) {
        if (filename == null) {
            return false;
        }

        String lowercaseFilename = filename.toLowerCase();
        for (String extension : extensionCollection) {
            if (lowercaseFilename.endsWith(extension)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemCollection - Collection of string items (all lowercase).
     * @param item           - Item to search for.
     * @return true if itemCollection contains the item, false otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean containsItem(Collection<String> itemCollection, String item) {
        return itemCollection.contains(item.toLowerCase());
    }

    private static boolean isNonEmpty(Object[] objArray) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < objArray.length && !result; index++) {
            if (objArray[index] != null) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String getTextMessage(String messageKey, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
        return getTextMessage(null, messageKey, args, locale);
    }

    private String getTextMessage(Object action, String messageKey, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            if ( action != null && useActionMessageBundle) {
                return LocalizedTextUtil.findText(action.getClass(), messageKey, locale);
            }
            return LocalizedTextUtil.findText(this.getClass(), messageKey, locale);                        
        } else {
            if ( action != null && useActionMessageBundle) {
                return LocalizedTextUtil.findText(action.getClass(), messageKey, locale, DEFAULT_MESSAGE, args);
            }
            return LocalizedTextUtil.findText(this.getClass(), messageKey, locale, DEFAULT_MESSAGE, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your `struts.xml`, where `xxxxxxxx` is the limit:

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First use validate method in your action file........

```
public void validate(){

  if(getFileUpload() !=null){

   System.out.println("======File size validation before upload: size in bytes: "+getFileUpload().length());

    if(getFileUpload().length()>202400){   

//Give the size in bytes whatever you want to take

    addActionError("File is too large ! Select less than 200Kb file");

      }else{

    addActionMessage("File Uploaded successfully!");

     }
   }
}
```

---

For complete code,please visit http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.com/2011/10/upload-file-using-in-struts-2.html