# How to override struts 2.2.3.1 file upload messages?

Tags: java, struts2

The `struts.messages.error.file.too.large` or `struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed` keys would pose interest to me. I've already tried to put them in a `"global.properties"`, `"struts-messages.properties"`, and `"ActionName_en_US.properties"` file and I have not seen either one of the messages that I wrote. I have **three `<s:file>` fields in a form** and the action to which it is submitted has the interceptors:

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
    <param name="allowedTypes">
        image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
    </param>
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="secureStack"></interceptor-ref>
```

The `secureStack` interceptor does not throw any errors.
EDIT: here's the definition of it:

```
    <interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor"
        class="client.interceptors.Authentication" />

    <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>
```

I used [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445791/struts-2-file-upload-interceptor-configuration-problems) and it seems to work but when one file exceeds the maximum size, the error message appears on the other two fields also.

Comment: Which theme do you use?

Comment: I use the default theme, it's not set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override struts.messages.error.file.too.large property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400820/how-to-override-struts-messages-error-file-too-large-property)

Comment: It isn't that because the version differs, and I already stated that I tried that solution, please read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since  comment was too long so i am answering your question.

### struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
```

you can put any other properties / constant in your xml file

create a  `global.properties` file with following

```
struts.messages.error.file.too.large=message
struts.messages.error.uploading=message
struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed=message
```

place this property file in same location as your `struts.xml` file.
Just make sure to ***clean & build*** before deploying and running. I am sure it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400820/how-to-override-struts-messages-error-file-too-large-property).

I've already use it past time. Tell us if it's work for you

Comment: I already mentioned I tried that, and the outside link present in the answer doesn't match my version of struts.